# Timeout with Python Requests + Clojure HttpKit Server but not Ring server

Tags: python, clojure, python-requests, ring, http-kit

I have some Ring routes which I'm running one of two ways.

1. `lein ring server`, with the `lein-ring` plugin
2. using `org.httpkit.server`, like  `(hs/run-server app {:port 3000}))`

It's a web app (being consumed by an Angular.js browser client).

I have some API tests written in Python using the Requests library:

```
my_r = requests.post(MY_ROUTE,
                     data=MY_DATA,
                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                     timeout=10)
```

When I use `lein ring server`, this request works fine in the JS client and the Python tests.

When I use `httpkit`, this works fine in the JS client but the Python client times out with

> socket.timeout: timed out

I can't figure out why the Python client is timing out. It happens with `httpkit` but not with `lein-ring`, so I can only assume that the cause is related to the difference.

- I've looked at the traffic in WireShark and both look like they give the correct response. Both have the same `Content-Length` field (15 bytes).
- I've raised the number of threads to 10 (shouldn't need to) and no change.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix this, but no satisfactory explanation.

I was using [`wrap-json-response`](https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/format_response.clj) Ring middleware to take a HashMap and convert it to JSON. I switched to doing my own conversion in my handler with [`json/write-str`](https://github.com/clojure/data.json), and this fixes it.

At a guess it might be something to do with the server handling output buffering, but that's speculation.

I've combed through the Wireshark dumps and I can't see any relevant differences between the two. The sent `Content-Length` fields are identical. The 'bytes in flight' differ, at 518 and 524.

No clue as to why the web browser was happy with this but Python Requests wasn't, and whether or this is a bug in `Requests`, `httpkit`, `ring-middleware-format` or my own code.

Comment: I'm having basically the same problem. FWIW, it looks like requests is ultimately using the base python socket library to read until it receives 10K bytes, or EOF. And then something in the call chain doesn't seem to be closing the connection. I'm still poking around looking for options.

Comment: Crazy. Please do report back, I'd love to know.